# load decision tree from file in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz

In python scikit learn, there is a method called export_graphviz to export a decision tree to dot file.

I want to ask if there is a method to import a dot file to scikit learn as a decision tree? like some function called sklearn.tree.import_graphviz() ?

Comment: That would be difficult to write.  Information needed to recreate the decision tree is quite likely not carried into the "dot" file and is lost.  The "dot" file is just to support graphviz, which is a general purpose utility and not specifically designed to represent decision trees.  I didn't see the necessary functions in the documentation, either.

Comment: It is not possible. `graphviz` is simply a picture representation of how and where your tree was split.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no easy way to do that. [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can only be used to visualise the decision tree. If you wish to save the model you can use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save the model. For example:

```
import cPickle
# save the classifier
with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    cPickle.dump(gnb, fid)    

# load it again
with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    gnb_loaded = cPickle.load(fid)
```